# A Very Modern Riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Here is my riddle:

```
I wasn't around in 1500,
but I sure am around now.
I existed 30 years ago,
but to use me, people would say “How?”.

I come in two main forms,
one portable; one not.
I'm very costly,
so you shouldn't throw me in a boiling pot.

You can use me for work,
or for play.
Or you can use me
for a school research day.

I am fairly small,
but I used to have a much bigger size.
Now when you guess what I am,
please don't tell me lies!
```

What am I?

Good luck!

Comment: This was simple, the only bit that confused me was the bit about lies. Does it have any connection? Like [_the answer_](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/44028/30537) never lies?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be more precise answer.

You can be a

> Computer

I wasn't around in 1500,
but I sure am around now.

> Computer didn't exist in 1500, but it does now.

I existed 30 years ago,
but to use me, people would say “How?”.

> It existed 30 years ago, and when using it first time, people would obviously ask how.

I come in two main forms,
one portable; one not.

> One is Desktop Computer, and other is Laptop

I'm very costly,
so you shouldn't throw me in a boiling pot.

> Computer is costly, therefore it must be used carefully.

You can use me for work,
or for play.
Or you can use me
for a school research day.

> It can be used for all above mentioned purposes.

I am fairly small,
but I used to have a much bigger size.
Now when you guess what I am,
please don't tell me lies!

> Well, computer was about a hall-size when invented, but now it is much smaller than before.

Answer (score 6):

Is it

> a phone?

*I wasn't around in 1500,

but I sure am around now.*

> Indeed.

*I existed 30 years ago,

but to use me, people would say “How?”.*

> 30 years ago, phones existed but were more old-fashioned and worked differently. "How?" might also be a humourous reference to tribal greetings, basically people say "Hi" to use a phone.

*I come in two main forms,

one portable; one not.*

> Mobile phones and landline phones.

*I'm very costly,

so you shouldn't throw me in a boiling pot.*

> Phones nowadays can cost hundreds of pounds.

*You can use me for work,

or for play.*

> You can do work (emails etc.) on a smartphone, or use it to play games or do pointless nonsense.

*Or you can use me

for a school research day.*

> I suppose so.

*I am fairly small,

but I used to have a much bigger size.*

> Mobile phones nowadays are small, but they used to be much bigger decades ago.

*Now when you guess what I am,

please don't tell me lies!*

> These lines are probably just decorative and not meant to be clues in themselves?

Comment: Not quite... but somewhat close.